# Does it make any difference if I give my input tags a value?

Tags: html

What's the functional difference between an `input` tag defined with an empty `value` attribute

```
<input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" value=""/>
```

and one with the `value` just omitted?

```
<input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
```

It's just a clean code thing for me, I'd love to stop putting in `value`s if they're not actually needed, but just about every form tutorial I've ever read in all my years programming has included them.

Are there negative consequences for *not* including them? My app seems to be functioning fine without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absence of a `value` attribute in `input` is equivalent to `value=""`, except for code that directly accesses the attribute (rather than the `value` property of the element node).

HTML5 CR defines the [`value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) so that when it is not present, the `value` property (“IDL attribute”) is set to the empty string (initially and on form reset). This accurately reflects browser behavior.

Thus, considering

```
<input id=a>
<input id=b value="">
```

they are equivalent, and `document.getElementById('a').value` is the empty string, just as for `'b'`. But `document.getElementById('a').getAttribute('value')` is the `null` object, not the empty string. The `null` object and the empty string are distinct values, even though they behave the same way in `==` comparison.

Thus, the difference would matter only if there is JavaScript code that accesses the attribute via the `getAttribute` method or the `attributes` property, which is not common for an attribute like `value`. Moreover, even then, the difference matters only if the code uses the attribute in a manner that deals with `null` and the empty string differently.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't been accessing value in that manner (I'm writing a Meteor application, so I have access in different ways).

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute is optional for type `text`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes

Comment: The question was whether there is any functional difference, not the syntax.

Comment: Can you give an example of a scenario where an optional element is beneficial with an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

for input tags of the 'text' type then value attribute is optional.  So (if empty) drop it.

Answer (score 0):

In some very old/exotic user-agents the `input` element might not work properly without the `value` attribute. However, in most cases by far, it would just take up (some) bytes without actually being of any use.

Comment: What user-agents would this apply to?

Comment: Not sure, @blaineh. I remember reading about it quite a while ago. I doubt it has any practical relevance today; especially if you expect to use relatively modern techniques.